# Given a X(G) coloring of the graph G, is it possible to find every other possible X(G)-coloring of G?

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

Given a coloring of the graph $G$ using $\chi(G)$ (the chromatic number of $G$) colors is it possible to find every other $\chi(G)$-coloring of $G$? One way of finding other $\chi(G)$-coloring of $G$ is by swapping 2 or more colors from the given coloring of $G$, an other way is by using Kempe chain recoloring. Are those two way of recoloring going to give me every possible $\chi(G)$-coloring of $G$? Is there a proof or a counter-proof to it? Is there other ways of recoloring without increasing the number of color used?

Comment: Is the graph connected?

Comment: What about the "[friendship graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friendship_graph)" $F_n$?

Comment: @bof Yes, the graph is connected. I think that even if a graph is not connected, a method can be inferred by analyzing each connected component of the graph individually.